# SQL: Order Month_year in date order

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a data which is

```
Monthyear (varchar)       Value
Jan 2019                   55
Feb 2019                   66
Jan 2020                   78
Feb 2020                   45
```

when i select the above statement as

```
select * from datatable order by Monthyear
```

the result is actually giving me

```
 Monthyear (varchar)       Value
    Feb 2019                   66
    Feb 2020                   45
    Jan 2019                   55
    Jan 2020                   78
```

But I want it in the month year order.
How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should store the "month-year" either as a date (first date of the month) or using a string that is sortable ("2019-01").

However, SQL Server is pretty good at converting strings to dates, so you can use:

```
order by convert(date, MonthYear)
```

This will convert by the date that you want.

Actually, you might want to add this to the table.  Say:

```
alter table datatable add yyyymm as (convert(date, MonthYear));
```

You can even persist this and add an index, if you have a lot of data in the table.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [CAST](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_cast.asp) to do this.

```
SELECT *
FROM   datatable
ORDER  BY Cast(monthyear AS DATE)
```

Result

```
+-----------+-------+
| Monthyear | Value |
+-----------+-------+
| Jan 2019  |    55 |
| Feb 2019  |    66 |
| Jan 2020  |    78 |
| Feb 2020  |    45 |
+-----------+-------+
```